# How do I get a compiled .app file from xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I click on the products folder in xcode and open the file in finder - I copy this to my text editor and it appears as folder and files. How can I get the compiled .app file?

Copied from products in xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the .app file here please check:

1. xCode window tab
2. Organizer
3. Right-click on the archive part, you can select which version you want to get the app file.
4. Show in finder
5. Right-click to (ProductName….). xcarchive file
6. Show package contents
7. Products
8. Applications

Comment: It still shows as uncompressed in my text editor.

Comment: I've updated my answer please check @Bomber